# Git - how to see the last commitment comments?

Tags: git, list, command-line, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [GIT: How to read last commit comment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7293008/git-how-to-read-last-commit-comment)

How can I see the comments on the last commitment from the command line

Comment: Yep, that's what I was looking for.... I couldn't find it in google, maybe the tags on that question are not so relevant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with `git log` you should see all old commits with the author, date and comment.

Comment: Can it be done without starting vi editor, and just the last commitment comments

Answer (score 1):

You can use `git log` to show a log of past commits. If you only want to see the last commit, you can use `git log -1`. The same pattern works for any number of past commits. So, `git log -5` will show the past 5 commits.

Comment: Definitely a duplicate, but thanks