# git subtree push lost my commit message

Tags: git, git-subtree

I have a git subtree `my-subtree` in my main repo `my-repo` that links to a remote repo.
I made a commit to files belonging to `my-subtree` in `my-repo`.

Then I wanted to push these changes back to the remote repo so I ran this command

```
git subtree push --prefix=remote_repos/my-subtree --squash git@github.com:my-userame/my-subtree master
```

It pushed the changes fine but the git commit message was lost! And I got this message instead

```
Merge commit '64cda2e4fd5e166e79cfc8e3c1edffa3fae40308'
```

How can I get my original git message into the remote repo when I perform the `git subtree push`? sintead of getting `Merge commit` message?

Comment: edited question: How can I get my original git message into the remote repo when I perform the `git subtree push`? sintead of getting `Merge commit` message

Answer (score 0):

You will find in many places in [`contrib/subtree/git-subtree.sh`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/subtree/git-subtree.sh) code like the one in [`add_squashed_msg`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b28aeab4ec1df28f3be3cb62ff4b85e5332d8d13/contrib/subtree/git-subtree.sh#L339-L346):

```sh
add_squashed_msg()
{
  if [ -n "$message" ]; then
    echo "$message"
  else
    echo "Merge commit '$1' as '$2'"
  fi
}
```

That refers to the [subtree option -m](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b28aeab4ec1df28f3be3cb62ff4b85e5332d8d13/contrib/subtree/git-subtree.sh#L87):

> `m,message=` use the given message as the commit message for the merge commit
>   options for '`split`'

(note: this isn't just for '`split`')

Set `-m` to the [last commit message](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7293026/6309).