# Git, read latest commit message when committing

Tags: git, git-commit

When I am committing, this text jumps up:

```
Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
 with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.

 On branch master
 Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 2 commits.

 Changes to be committed:

    new file:   modules/new_file.txt
```

What I want is to let this informative text also show me the message of my last commit, without me needing to go through `git log`, `git show` or anything similar.

E.g.

```
(...)

 Changes to be committed:

    new file:   modules/new_file.txt

 Previous commit message:
    [FIX] Fixed the foo.bar module
```

This is exactly the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7293008/git-how-to-read-last-commit-comment), but none of the answers was actually answering the question, so I guess OP just asked it a bit wrong?

Comment: No, I am using Windows with Atom, Sublime or Notepad++. Havent decided yet, but currently I am testing out Atom.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a [git hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) called `prepare-commit-msg` which is what generates this commit message template. There should be a `prepare-commit-msg.sample` file in your `.git` directory by default. Rename it to remove the `.sample` and then edit it to include a `git log -1` or anything else you might want and you'll get it when you commit.

Something like this

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "# Previous commit:" >> $1
git log -1 -p|sed 's/^\(.\)/# \1/g'  >> $1
```

should be enough.

Comment: Okay, I am not that familiar with bash scripts, trying to add `echo something`, `dir`, `ls` at the top of this does nothing. Could you provide a minimal working example? EDIT: I see that it spits something out in git bash before opening the commit editor. So my problem is getting into the comment section in the commit message

Answer (score 1):

You could write your own command? It might look something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Last commit message:"
git log -1 --pretty=%B # only echo commit msg to console
echo "Enter commit message:"
read commitmsg # let user enter a commit message
git commit -m "$commitmsg"
```

You would then add this file to your PATH.