# Copy the last commit summary into the new commit summary in GitHub Desktop

Tags: git, github, github-desktop

When committing some files, I sometimes prefer to get the last commit summary and edit it. Is there any way to easily copy the last commit summary in GitHub Desktop?

I use the latest version of GitHub Desktop, viz. 3.0.1.1 on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

In Eclipse EGIT I can do so clicking on:

[image]

Comment: You can amend your last commit in Git. Is that what you are talking about?

Comment: @GregBurghardt No, I think Franck wants to use the previous commit as a basis for writing the new one. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32046680/2541573

Comment: Jubobs is correct, that's what I was trying to ask :)