# Track cherry-picks across branches

Tags: git, github, atlassian-sourcetree

I am using Sourcetree and GitHub for a while now, and I have noticed there is missing some essential functionality that, in my opinion, would facilitate and speed up development.

When having multiple branches and fixing a bug on the `master` branch, I wish to cherry-pick this fix to another branche (let's say `/test-branch`). Later on, I wish to cherry-pick from `/test-branch` to `/live-branch`.

Is there, in some way, a possibility to track of ALL my cherry-picks done from the commit on the `master` branch and to see on which branches this commit is performed? I want some sort of output like:

```
[abc123] --commit SHA
    -> /master
    -> /test-branch
    -> /live-branch
```

**EDIT**
I have found a webpage where something similar is resolved:

https://adamprescott.net/2015/10/02/tracking-commits-across-branches-with-git-and-sourcetree/

Here commits can be tracked accross branches using a Custom action. However, since cherry-picking results in an entirely new commit, the cherry-pick SHA does not correspond to the original commit SHA, thus does not work in my case.

Comment: Note that the original branch might disappear. And even the original commit, if for example it is rebased after being cherry-picked from. Tracking is hard in the general case

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [daggy-fix merges for keeping track](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2925419/6309) of your cherry-pick.

But the more general solution described in "[Is there a way to figure out where a commit was cherry-pick'ed from?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2937724/6309)" proposes a script which can help determine which commit is a cherry-pick from another commit.
You would still need to script in order to get the result you want though.

Comment: Since cherry-picking maintains the original commit message, I would already be satisfied with searching by commit message. 'git log --grep="<commit subject>" --all'. Is there a command to get the current commit's message? Like $SHA gets you the commit's SHA

Comment: Yes, that is the idea, but you still need to script that search.

Comment: I can put that in a Custom Action then, no? I just need to know if there is a command to get the current commit's message? Similar to $SHA that gets the SHA of the current commit

Comment: @RazorAlliance192 There should be such a command: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7293026/6309, like `git log -1 --pretty=%B`