# how can jenkins get push commit when polling on a git project

Tags: git, jenkins

I have a jenkins task which polls on a git repo.

It is triggered on every git push to that git repo.

Is there any way Jenkins can get the last push message?

**UPDATE**

I want my current jenkins task to trigger a build on another Jenkins task with the commit message as a parameter.

what is the syntax for that?

like this?

[image]

Comment: Have a look at - https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Changelog+Plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is define as a first build step which would [get the last commit message](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7293026/6309):

```
git log -1 --pretty=%B
```

Then, with a plugin like the [EnvInject+Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin), you can inject the result into an environment variable that other build step can then reuse.

Comment: Thanks. I want to pass it as a build param to another jenkins projects
how can i do this? like i show in my updated question?